# Android Studio Build failed when using Google Play services for AdMob

Tags: android, admob

I've just finished making my app and I am now trying to implement AdMob ads. I'm using Android Studio and this is how I've done it.

First, I added Google Play services as a dependency

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':zip_file')
compile project(':wheel')
compile project(':shake_detector')
compile project(':facebook')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
```

}

I then added the necessary things to AndroidManifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

And then I added Ads to XML

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1606xxxx7xx50xx0/xxxx160xx2"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

As soon as I added Ads to XML, an error showed in the XML editor:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 57
Exception Details:
  Location:
com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.onMeasure(II)V @20: ifnull
  Reason:
Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
0000000: 033e 0336 042a 03b6 0015 3a05 2ab6 0014
0000010: 3a06 1905 c600 2519 05b6 000b 1008 9f00
0000020: 1b2a 1905 1b1c b600 1919 05b6 000a 3e19
0000030: 05b6 0009 3604 a700 1f19 06c6 001a 2ab6
0000040: 0016 3a07 1906 1907 b600 133e 1906 1907
0000050: b600 1236 041d 2ab6 0018 b800 2a3e 1504
0000060: 2ab6 0017 b800 2a36 042a 1d1b b800 0d15
0000070: 041c b800 0db6 001a b1                 

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1718)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:310)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:100)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:206)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
at     com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:393)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:337)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:575)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:564)
at     com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at     com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:564)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:691)
at     org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:604)
at     org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1900(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at     org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:546)
at     com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at     com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
at     com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
at     com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
at     org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:541)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Now everytime I try to run the app (or build project), this is the error I get

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Android Development\Android Studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\android-support-v4-ee598d69cced4ae2d0367cf320b535877ffadf7a.jar C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\bolts-70810bd866f930573e290daf7ec3dc1948286267.jar C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-0c36385bc77adc652fbbca692188f2ba3a839958.jar C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-2599f9358b4e94ed98b20719bc88ed4c00c1bfff.jar C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-3a8f3fce0efbd622d28c51e87741fcdeac2d6970.jar C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-407783d6a24b188172e1a767d67e0a0b4dae5728.jar C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-8067c76d4a10c4f3c1e28bb6e233007f282b8655.jar C:\Users\whizs_000\AndroidStudioProjects\Sleepwithnaturesounds\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-3704bce472ca0d2a13ecadbd5f94b970f7bf2d0e.jar
>   Error Code:
>       2
>       Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define     Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

Any idea what could be wrong? Last time I was implementing ads, I was doing it in Eclipse so I'm a bit new here in AS.

Comment: Please make sure that you don't include any superfluous libraries, e.g., the v4 support library.

Comment: No, I don't include any of those libraries. You can see all of the libraries that I include since i pasted my dependencies.

Comment: I don't know if any library is included, e.g, via your `libs/` folder, which is a common mistake. Please check it.

Comment: I don't have any libraries included via libs/ folder. But I just checked all my other libraries and I noticed that the Facebook library that I'm using for sharind over Facebook has android-suppor-v4.jar inside libs folder. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: I removed the jar from facebook sdk and it now works! Thank you very much for this! But I sadly have a new problem. My app now successfully compiles but now when the activity that is containing AdMob opens, I get a LogCat error "GooglePlayServices are not available due to error 2". Any idea how to solve that also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59424/discussion-between-cygery-and-whiz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/[...]

This indicates that a superfluous/duplicate library is included in the build process. Please check the `libs/` folders in the project and any included library.

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'

Please use version 5.0.89 instead of 5.2.08 because the latter version isn't rolled out yet and apps using it can't be published on Google Play.